# Header image will not center correctly

Tags: html, image

I'm making a site and trying to center the image head. However, it doesn't appear to be working.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="templatemo_header">
        <div class="image"><img src="images/server_banner_lax_en5.png" alt="Header"></div>  
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
#templatemo_header {
    height: 263px;
    border-top: 5px solid #FFF;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 762px;
    float: left;
    background: url(images/templatemo_headerimg_bg.jpg);
}
#templatemo_header .image {
    width: 762px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I tried to add `margin: 0 auto;` to the image, but it still is not centered. How can I do this?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: you need the header part in center ? please paste your relevance code.

Comment: This question is going to be junk in 6 months (or the moment you update your site), if you don't put some code in your question as a reference to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the css for the div containing your image with:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapping div is the same width as the image, this stops any margins from being automatically applied since there is no space.

There are a few ways to fix this, but easiest would be to set the width of templatemo_header (the wrapper div) to 100%. This way the image margins can expand, thereby centering the image.

So in your css, modify the width from 762px to 100%, like so:

```
#templatemo_header {
    height: 263px;
    border-top: 5px solid #FFF;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: url(images/templatemo_headerimg_bg.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS file:

`.image { width:762px; margin:0 auto;}`